# How to normalize parts of matrix elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

To normalize the last 2 or more columns of a matrix,

```
m = {{0, 0, 135, 276}, {0, 1, 762, 852}, {0, 2, 762, 852}, {1, 0, 162,
852}, {1, 1, 362, 852}, {1, 2, 262, 852}}
```

I can do that by

```
mm = Transpose@
 m /. {m[[All, 3]] -> m[[All, 3]]/(m[[All, 3]] + m[[All, 4]]), 
 m[[All, 4]] -> m[[All, 4]]/(m[[All, 3]] + m[[All, 4]])} // Transpose // MatrixForm
```

Or step by step

```
mt = Transpose[ m]

msum=mt[[3]]+mt[[4]]

m3=mt[[3]]/msum

m4=mt[[4]]/msum

mlast = Transpose[mt /. {mt[[3]] -> m3, mt[[4]] -> m4}]
```

are there any more elegant method in Mathematica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you normalize by the 3rd and the 4th element by the sum of these two elements, right?

Based on that, we might not want to use `Normalize` and divide directly:

```
#/{1, 1, #[[3]] + #[[4]], #[[3]] + #[[4]]} & /@ m
```

Comment: That's wonderful! thank Dirk.